# Getting an error when switching to iFrame on iOS Safari mobile browser with appium

Tags: appium, ios, safari

Original error when I'm trying switch to iframe.
Same code working fine with desktop browsers.
This happens only with safari mobile browser.
I'm on appium v1.20.2

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://xxxxx.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I found this post but that was 3 years ago,so is there any new solutions for this?
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/80927

Answer (score 1):

For the last 30 hours I was looking for a solution and couldn’t find a solution for safari iOS. As a workaround I just extract the iframe's src URL at the middle of my test and I navigate to the iframe's URL,

This is how it looks like, and now I was able to perform my test steps.

```
String ccURL = driver.findElement(frmPayment).getAttribute("src").toString();
driver.navigateTo(ccURL);
```